# Invoke SET method in Java by given a String

Tags: java

I have a string variable which dependes on "i" variable, i want to call this string, like his method:

```
String nameSetClassifiedMethod= "setClassficationdesc" + i;
```

and i wanted something like this:

```
this.nameSetClassifiedMethod( some parametersIn);
```

I know this is not possible, because i can't invoke a method with a string like im doing, but i don't know any solutions for this.

I have some code that's whic is not mine, which is doing something like:

```
if (i == 0) {this.setClassficationdesc0(..)}
if (i == 1) {this.setClassficationdesc1(..)}
if (i == 2) {this.setClassficationdesc2(..)}
```

So i'm trying to invoke the method by string to reduce complexity

Comment: You can use the reflection API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/ However, there might be a better design such as having a method `setClassficationdesc` that takes `i` as a parameter.

Comment: Only resort to reflection if you *absolutely have to*.

Answer (score 0):

Well you *could* call the method from a string variable using reflection.  But instead, I suggest the following workflow:

```java
String i = "One";

switch (i) {
    case "One":
        // call setClassficationdescOne(...)
        break;

    case "Two":
        // call setClassficationdescTwo(...)
        break;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Please search and read the topic "Reflection in Java". In particular look at class [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and in it look at method `getMethod`. so you can do:

```
Method method = this.getClass().getMethod(...);
```

Once you get the method you can invoke it. (See Javadoc for class `Method`)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you would use reflection by doing something like the following:

```java
String nameSetClassifiedMethod= "setClassficationdesc" + i;
Method method = Operations.class.getDeclaredMethod("nameSetClassifiedMethod", String.class); //here you should adapt it to your method's signature
method.setAccessible(true);
// and then
ClassWhichHoldsReflectedMethod instance = new ClassWhichHoldsReflectedMethod(); 
method.invoke(instance, params...);
```

Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-reflection) out for more.

Comment: That's not why im looking for, im trying to reduce complexity

Comment: Could you update your question with a more realistic scenario?

Comment: Hey @RoyalUp any more doubts about this? If my answer resolved or helped you resolve your question please mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for Java 14 [*Switch Expressions*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html):

```
int i = // initializing the variable
    
switch (i) {
    case 0 -> this.setClassficationdesc0(..); // perform a side-effect
    case 1 -> this.setClassficationdesc1(..); // perform a side-effect
    case 2 -> this.setClassficationdesc2(..); // perform a side-effect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited number of `setClassificationdesc#()` methods and you know them upfront, try something like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    @FunctionalInterface
    private interface ClassificationdescSetter
    {
        public void set( … );
    }

    private final ClassificationdescSetter [] m_CDSetters;
    public YourClass( … )
    {
        …
        m_CDSetters = new ClassificationdescSetters [] {this::setClassificationdesc1, this::setClassificationdesc2, this::setClassificationdesc3, … };
        …
    }

    public final void doSomething( final int i )
    {
        m_CDSetters [i - 1].set( … );
    }
}
```

Of course, all error handling is missing here!

The interface is obsolete (at least redundant) if the signature for `setClassificationdesc#()` matches an already existing functional interface. In that case, use the existing interface as the type for `m_CDSetters`; you may have to use another method as `set()`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [method handles](https://www.baeldung.com/java-method-handles).

```java
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodType;

public class MthdHndl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
        int index = 0;
        String name = "setClassficationdesc";
        MethodType type = MethodType.methodType(String.class, int.class);
        try {
            MethodHandle mh = lookup.findVirtual(George.class, name + index, type);
            int parameter = 2;
            String result = (String) mh.invoke(new George(), parameter);
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        catch (Throwable x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class George {
    private static final String[] FORTUNE = new String[]{"Long live the revolution!",
                                                         "Have a nice day.",
                                                         "Behind every argument is someone's ignorance."};

    public String setClassficationdesc0(int i) {
        return FORTUNE[i];
    }
}
```

Note that since the method being invoked (via `MethodHandle`) is an instance method, the first parameter to method `invoke` is the instance on which to invoke the method.